# WiX v3.7 - How to remove file in uninstall that was created after installation

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, wix3.7, uninstallation

I'm creating an installer for a program using WiX. The program creates a log file and a .dat file in the program directory during the configuration process (after complete installation). How do I tell WiX to remove these files during the uninstallation process if they are not present during the installation process?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: BTW—Windows Installer is the software that does the installing so it sounds odd to say "tell WiX to...."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to define the problem out of existence by installing those files. That is, create and install an empty log file and a dat file—initialized to whatever empty or default is for it.

Another way is to put `RemoveFile` elements under the `Component` element that is most closely associated with the use those files (e.g., the program exe).

---

Are you sure you want writable files in the same directory as the program? Usually, programs are installed so that only administrators can change them. If the program uses data that any user can change to affect all users, the data would be stored under the ALLUSERS profile. And, data that a user can change that affects only that user would be stored under that user's profile.

When data is stored that way, it is a question as to when or even whether such data should be deleted. A user might want that data preserved for the next installation of the program even if the user doesn't know how the data is persisted.

Comment: The RemoveFile worked great for the .dat file, which is always called the same thing. However, the log files have dynamic names according to the date they were created. Is there any way to reference a file that you don't know the full name of?

Comment: I just found the answer to my own question. To remove a file that you do not know the full name of, it is possible to add a wildcard in the 'Name' property of the <RemoveFile> element

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me - use custom command and delete using "del" or "rmdir"

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Forced-remove-of-folder-and-files-within-td698425.html

```
<Product>
    <CustomAction Id="Cleanup_logfile" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" 
    ExeCommand="cmd /C &quot;del install.log&quot;" 
    Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="Cleanup_logfile" After="RemoveFiles" >
        REMOVE="ALL" 
      </Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
</Product>
```